# assign data to variable with event received data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue js I have a problem with assign data to a variable inside the event block. when I fire the event from the component with ID, after getting the ID from the event I send a request to the server to get data. after getting data, I assign them to an object in Vuejs. when I console.log the data in the event block it shows data but it's not showing data out of the event block.

```js
 mounted() {
            Fire.$on('orderId', (id) => {
                axios.get('/api/order/'+id).then(({data}) => {
                this.order = data.order;
                this.orders_details = data.order_details;
                    console.log(this.order.BillNo) //Show the bill No;
                 });
            });
            console.log(this.order.BillNo) //Not Show the bill No. it empty object; 
        },
```

Comment: what is the solution

Comment: what's the objective of the `object` what you want to do with `billNo`

Comment: I wanna take data from the order controller in Laravel. bill no is just a demo I wanna take all data after adding a new order. I wanna print it.

Comment: that why after adding new order I am sending the ID in the event in anther component on anther component I want to take data for print.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments with @Satyam, maybe a watcher could help?

```
watch: { 
  order() {
    if(this.order && this.order.BillNo)
      this.doSomethingWith(this.order.BillNo) // callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you want to do with the data. The primary "problem" is that you are working here with asynchronous call.

```js
 mounted() {
            Fire.$on('orderId', (id) => {
                axios.get('/api/order/'+id).then(({data}) => {
                this.order = data.order;
                this.orders_details = data.order_details;
                    console.log(this.order.BillNo) // fires after the request
                 });
            });
            console.log(this.order.BillNo) // fires immediately bevor request
        },
```

In most cases the following will be the solution:

```
<div v-if="order">...</div>
<my-loader v-else/>
```